# findelementsbycss in vba with selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, css-selectors

i can't manage to extract certain links from a website with css.
i don't really know css yet either and am just finding my way around it.
i have 2 questions one specific how to find the element, and at the end again how to examine the element in css.

1.

Inspection of the site with markers

[image]

i am trying to get the two links marked in green, as marker i would like to use either the red marked link text or  above it.

my attempted code:

```
    Set Elements = GC.FindElementsByCss("table.TABLE tbody tr td p iframe ")
    a = 0
    For Each Element In Elements
         ReDim Preserve href(a) As String
        href(a) = Element.Attribute("innerText")
        a = a + 1
    Next Element
```

2. 

can i somehow examine the elements in vba?
if i know what is stored in them, i could search for the desired value under Value and then use the expression.
I think under Watches I once had the possibility to see all the different values for an element like innerText, href, outerhtml, innerhtml and so on.

In [VBA Watches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQdAn.png) at the moment i only see a small overview

[image]

Comment: Would answering your first question _how to find the element_ be sufficient? Currently your question is too broad as per Stackoverflow standards.

Comment: definitely yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60914156

Comment: But @QHarr my iframe has no attribute like id, name, class or tag

Comment: You can use FindElementsBy and then index into the returned WebElements collection e.g. select the first element (iframe) or second .... after selecting all iframes within current document.

Comment: You can get the links that have the class ``loadbutton`` and then you search for the links that have ``LinkText``.

Comment: ok i was able to get three elements with "Set Elements = GC.FindElementsByCss("iframe")".  // but from then on I don't really get on with all my attempts.  //
after some trial and error I found "innerHTML" and with href(a) = Element.Attribute("innerHTML") I get three entries: "", "loading . . ",loading . ."
With GC.FindElementsByCss("iframe a.loadbutton")" i get no elements.
also attempts like "GC.FindElementsByCss("iframe html body a[class='loadbutton']")" failed ith zero elements

Comment: The url that you're using is public? If it is, can you share it?

Comment: yes the link is "public" but rather in the gray area. i have "hidden" it behind a bit.ly link so that everyone can decide for themselves after the warning beforehand. It is a download page from which a tried to get the ddl.to link. https://shorturl.at/fpwEP (shorturl works here, and bit.ly  which is blocked here warns)