# VBA & Selenium | Access iframe within HTML containing #document

Tags: javascript, vba, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

I am trying to access the HTML within two iframes using Selenium Basic in VBA, as IE has been blocked on our machines, and Python, etc. are not available to us.

Previously I could access the html with this:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

' actual website excluded as it is a work hosted website which requires login, etc.
website = "..."
IE.navigate (website)

Dim IEDocument As HTMLDocument
Set IEDocument = IE.document.getElementById(id1).contentDocument.getElementById(id2).contentDocument
```

From there I would have access to all the HTML elements which I could work with.

Now I am trying the following with Selenium Basic:

```
Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
website = "..."

cd.Start baseUrl:=website

cd.Get "/"
Dim af1 As Selenium.WebElement, af2 As Selenium.WebElement
Set af1 = cd.FindElementById("CRMApplicationFrame")
Set af2 = af1.FindElementById("WorkAreaFrame1")
```

It works up to the last line, as it is able to set af to the "CRMApplicationFrame" id; however, I am unable to get inside of it.

I think the solution lies in executing a bit of JavaScript, similar to as in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phYGCGXGtEw

Although I don't have a #ShadowDOM line, I do have a #document line.

Based on and trying to adapt the video I have tried the following:

```
Set af2 = cd.ExecuteScript(Script:="return arguments[0].contentDocument", arguments:=af1 )
```

However, that did not work.

I also tested:

```
Dim af1 As Selenium.WebElement
Set af1 = cd.FindElementById("CRMApplicationFrame")
call cd.SwitchToFrame (af1)

Debug.Print cd.PageSource
```

However, the SwitchToFrame line won't execute, with a 438 error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any advice or guidance on how I could succeed would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
call cd.SwitchToFrame (af1)
```

with:

```
cd.SwitchToFrame "CRMApplicationFrame"
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Selenium VBA Excel - problem clicking a link within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60914156/7429447)